# Change color of logo-text on scroll through div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any other solution to do this without using a clip-path on the whole `div` parent and then reducing this clip-path with JavaScript? Every time I do this, I use JavaScript for changing clip-paths dynamically, but now the project doesn't allow me to use it. So this code below worked, but I need another solution.

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
let num = window.pageYOffset * 100 / document.querySelector('.wrap').getBoundingClientRect().height

document.querySelector('.wrap').style.clipPath = `polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% ${100-num}%, 0% ${100-num}%)`;


})
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrap{
  height: 500px;  
  background-color:blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);   
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  
}

.sticky{    
  position: sticky;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 750px;
  background-color:red;
}

.green{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class="sticky">
    text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div">
  <div class="sticky green">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mix-blend-mode ? possible example  https://jsfiddle.net/7o4r6bx8/  see specification on mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: Yes this is good solution, but i need whole navigation to change. For text it maybe work, but problem is because i need to change logo with different image.

Comment: it is not using text here ? you can even use different image : https://jsfiddle.net/anL2uqmv/ (i used a filter to modify the colors ) or with gray/colored image : https://jsfiddle.net/anL2uqmv/1/ ;)